# Frequent hash collisions when hashing 3d coordinates

Tags: c++, hash, hash-collision

I'm trying to hash a 3d coordinate to make a unique ID for an index to a map

my approach is currently

```
return hash(x + hash(y + hash(z)));
```

Or in c++

```
struct ChunkHasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(FLOAT3 const& vec) const
    {
        return std::hash<float>()(
            vec.x + std::hash<float>()(
                vec.y + std::hash<float>() (vec.z)
                )
            );
    }
}chunkHasher;
```

but the problem is i'm getting *loads* of hash collisions...
just running this test, both `vec(0,0,0)` and `vec(-1,0,0)` map onto each other

I feel like this *should* work, hash collisions should approach happening only `2.32831e-08%` of the time by my rough calculations...  am I missing something?

Edit:
Within an execution of my program a given input should hash into the same output whenever calculated, so having some kind of internal state to the hasher that is changed with each call is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec.y + std::hash<float>() (vec.z)` is adding `std::size_t` and `float`. The result will be a float, but since the integer will be on average 32-digit long, adding a small float with 7 digits to it will easily yield the same float value.

```cpp
std::size_t operator()(FLOAT3 const& vec) const
{
    std::hash<float> h;

    return h(h(vec.x)+ h(h(vec.y)+ h(vec.z)));
}
```

Something like this could be used, it hashes the individual elements and uses the nested scheme to break the order in-dependency of simply adding the 3 hashes.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a hash combiner that makes it unlikely that different things hash the same.

Like with hash(a)+hash(b)+hash(c)  will be the same for (a,b,c) is (1,2,3), (3,1,2), (2,1,3), (2,3,1) etc.

The typical hash combine looks like e.g.

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}
```

So example: making live demo

**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82c628eaaf210f7f)**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
{
    std::hash<T> constexpr hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}

struct FLOAT3 { float x, y, z; };

template <> struct std::hash<FLOAT3> {
    size_t operator()(FLOAT3 const& f3) const {
        size_t v = 0x778abe;
        hash_combine(v, f3.x);
        hash_combine(v, f3.y);
        hash_combine(v, f3.z);
        return v;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::hash<FLOAT3> constexpr h;
    using std::setw;

    for (auto x : {.1f, 1e19f, 8e-9f })
    for (auto y : {.1f, 1e19f, 8e-9f })
    for (auto z : {.1f, 1e19f, 8e-9f })
        std::cout
            << setw(6) << x << "\t"
            << setw(6) << y << "\t"
            << setw(6) << z << " -> "
            << std::hex << h({x,y,z}) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
   0.1     0.1     0.1 -> 2022fc2207a6ab25
   0.1     0.1   1e+19 -> 919c9922fe821886
   0.1     0.1   8e-09 -> 960d84a2d4678d2b
   0.1   1e+19     0.1 -> 684a4180fc444de
   0.1   1e+19   1e+19 -> 596abb1854ebd77d
   0.1   1e+19   8e-09 -> 5cfb5c987a856ae0
   0.1   8e-09     0.1 -> f145ea71ac741736
   0.1   8e-09   1e+19 -> 26f7c77185489897
   0.1   8e-09   8e-09 -> 3b66a3f1d8b53520
 1e+19     0.1     0.1 -> c80abe72bee6c866
 1e+19     0.1   1e+19 -> 39789b73658d5881
 1e+19     0.1   8e-09 -> 32e9f6f35327e674
 1e+19   1e+19     0.1 -> 373b5488877d347d
 1e+19   1e+19   1e+19 -> c6cd7b88d050a5da
 1e+19   1e+19   8e-09 -> f95d9f082a3a124f
 1e+19   8e-09     0.1 -> 94a1f8f73e8fa675
 1e+19   8e-09   1e+19 -> 255fe5f0c5b43694
 1e+19   8e-09   8e-09 -> 2acec070ea4e8067
 8e-09     0.1     0.1 -> 799dd2b873ce62ba
 8e-09     0.1   1e+19 -> c82fb7b808ea9215
 8e-09     0.1   8e-09 -> c3bc9a39de8d3ca8
 8e-09   1e+19     0.1 -> 9112c88effbc9643
 8e-09   1e+19   1e+19 -> 6080eb8ec690671c
 8e-09   1e+19   8e-09 -> 6f70100e28fdf071
 8e-09   8e-09     0.1 -> f660883bf4d4c4ac
 8e-09   8e-09   1e+19 -> 48f6ed3badf8b40b
 8e-09   8e-09   8e-09 -> 4c41c0bb9b1522be
```

Comment: Added some test inputs for demonstration